# jQuery - Is it possible to use the nth-child number in an equation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, this is probably a dumb question but I have 10 h1 elements that I want to fade gradually as they show up.

Is it possible to have something like

```
var opac = 1 - Number(n)/10;
```

and then use that as the value for opacity...

```
$('h1:nth-child(n)').css('opacity', opac)
```

I realize this code doesn't really work, but is there a way to do this, use the nth-child number in a variable or an equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is .each. You have to loop and apply.

```
$('h1').each(function(index){
  var opacity = 1 - (index/10);
  $(this).css("opacity",opacity);
})
```

Comment: Opacity value ranges is from 0 to 1... `10 - (index/10)` leads to out of range value.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette True that. There is a typo I have. It's 1.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Almost. Just a line shorter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No.

For CSS rules, there is no knowledge of how elements are rendered.
This has to be done using script.

I suggest this:

```
$("h1").each(function){
  var n = $(this).index();
  var opacity = 1 - (n/10);
  $(this).css({"opacity":opacity);
});
```